# Pipe file to gnome-open command

Tags: command-line, gnome, bash, bashrc

For example I want to open a specific book from `Books` directory.

To find it I do `ls | grep -i 'book_i_want'`
Ideally I would like to add next pipe with command, like this:
`ls | grep -i 'some_book' | gnome-open`
But that do not work.

What will be the correct command?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the initial question, you would pipe through `xargs` if you wanted to launch something with STDIN as an argument.

```
ls | ... | xargs gnome-open
```

Or you could treat the output like an argument directly. This is less useful in *very* long directories as you might hit the argument limit. `xargs` is almost certainly faster.

```
gnome-open $(ls | ...)
```

But [**you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` in commands**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); both of those are rubbish.
You can roll all your searching and filtering into one command:

```
find -iname '*book_i_want*' -exec gnome-open {} +
```

Note that this will recurse into subdirectories by default (different from the `ls` default) so either account for that or add `-maxdepth 1` to the line.

Answer (score 3):

If this works:

```
ls | grep -i 'book_i_want'
```

Then, so will this

```
gnome-open *book_i_want*
```

To make it case insensitive:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
gnome-open *book_i_want*
```

In fact, both of the above will work better than using `ls` since they can deal with any file name, including those with whitespace and strange characters, which `ls` can't.